# Graphic elements won't apear in JFrame (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm in the middle of working on a program. I created a JFrame with a bunch of panels, buttons, labels and textfields that are supposed to be inside it. For some reason the JFrame apears, but with nothing inside it. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    JButton rect,oval,tri,free,addPoint;
    JLabel xLabel,yLabel;
    JTextField xTextField,yTextField;
    JPanel leftPanel,rightPanel,optionsPanel,pointsPanel;

    public GUI(){
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Graphics Generator");
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);

        add(leftPanel);
        add(rightPanel);

        leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));
        leftPanel.add(optionsPanel);

        optionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,2,2));

        rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
        oval = new JButton("Oval");
        tri = new JButton("Triangle");
        free = new JButton("Free Shape");

        optionsPanel.add(rect);
        optionsPanel.add(oval);
        optionsPanel.add(tri);
        optionsPanel.add(free);

        leftPanel.add(pointsPanel);

        pointsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,2,2));

        pointsPanel.add(xLabel);
        pointsPanel.add(xTextField);
        pointsPanel.add(yLabel);
        pointsPanel.add(yTextField);
        pointsPanel.add(addPoint);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI gui = new GUI();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

- your `JComponents` aren't initialized,
- you added `JComponents` to already visible `JFrame`,
- you have to move code line  `setVisible(true);` to the end of constructor,
- Swing GUI should be crated on [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 1):

None of your panels, textfields, or labels have been initialized. I'm getting `NullPointerException`

The code below will get your program running. But you really need to look into some [**LayoutManagers**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

```
private void initUI(){
    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel = new JPanel();
    optionsPanel = new JPanel();
    pointsPanel = new JPanel();

    yLabel = new JLabel();
    xLabel = new JLabel();

    xTextField = new JTextField();
    yTextField = new JTextField();

    add(leftPanel);
    add(rightPanel);

    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));
    leftPanel.add(optionsPanel);

    optionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,2,2));

    rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
    oval = new JButton("Oval");
    tri = new JButton("Triangle");
    free = new JButton("Free Shape");
    addPoint = new JButton("Add Point");

    optionsPanel.add(rect);
    optionsPanel.add(oval);
    optionsPanel.add(tri);
    optionsPanel.add(free);

    leftPanel.add(pointsPanel);

    pointsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,2,2));

    pointsPanel.add(xLabel);
    pointsPanel.add(xTextField);
    pointsPanel.add(yLabel);
    pointsPanel.add(yTextField);
    pointsPanel.add(addPoint);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Graphics Generator");
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke `setVisible(true)` after you're done adding your components. They won't render otherwise until there's a call to `revalidate()`;

You also need to initialise your components before trying to use them.

Example:

```
leftPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel = new JPanel();
add(leftPanel);
add(rightPanel);
```

Repeat for the other components.